# Why bash script using if and grep works one every other call?

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, grep

```
root@xxx:/#  [ "`date | grep 20 | echo $?`" -gt "0" ] && echo 12
root@xxx:/#  [ "`date | grep 20 | echo $?`" -gt "0" ] && echo 12
12
root@xxx:/#  [ "`date | grep 20 | echo $?`" -gt "0" ] && echo 12
root@xxx:/#  [ "`date | grep 20 | echo $?`" -gt "0" ] && echo 12
12
root@xxx:/#  [ "`date | grep 20 | echo $?`" -gt "0" ] && echo 12
root@xxx:/#  [ "`date | grep 20 | echo $?`" -gt "0" ] && echo 12
12
```

It should echo 12 on every line, but do so only on odd lines. Why?
How to fix?

Comment: You should paste the relevant code here. A link with a picture to it in an external service does not seem the right approach to get this answered IMHO.

Comment: See [why not upload images of code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: added code here

Comment: Note that you should use the `{}` button, not the snippet button, for almost all code -- StackSnippets are for HTML+JavaScript code that can be run in a browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assuming that `foo | echo $?` will show the exit status of `foo`. This is not the case. Instead, it shows the exit status of the previous command or pipeline:

```
$ bash -c 'exit 42'
$ true | echo $?
42
```

Your command therefore flip-flops like this one:

```
$ [ $? = 1 ] && echo "Boop"
$ [ $? = 1 ] && echo "Boop"
Boop
$ [ $? = 1 ] && echo "Boop"
$ [ $? = 1 ] && echo "Boop"
Boop
```

What you intended was to suppress `grep` output (here done with `-q`), and then add a second command (after a `;`) that can write out the value:

```
# Check for success when running a command and writing out
# the exit status and capturing it and comparing it to success
[ "`date | grep -q 20; echo $?`" -gt "0" ] && echo 12
```

However, you can drop all the redundancies and just do:

```
# Check for success when running a command
date | grep -q 20 && echo 12
```

Comment: Of course, `grep 20` will match on dates like 1920-12-31 and 1999-06-20. We have no idea whether these should actually be matches; I'm guessing not.